# How can I add a new document with fields to a firebase collection with the autoid in swift ui

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I would like to add a document to my database collection using autoid with fields that I assign the name to in swift ui .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a reference of the database:

```
var db: Firestore!
```

then you can reference it with:

```
db.collection()
```

For example, if I wanted to add a person's name under a unique id:

```
db.collection("users").addDocument(data: [
"name": nameTextField.text // Change this to the variable you want to save
]) { err in
if let err = err {
    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
} else {
    print("Document successfully written!")
}
}
```

If you create the document without an explicit Id, our SDK will auto-generate a random one for you.

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) are a good source of information too.